# Google OR Tools: Scheduling worker to work multiple shifts

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools

I'm building off of the shift scheduling code from OR Tools (https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py) and trying to have the option to schedule an employee to multiple shifts only if necessary.

I have 7 employees who have different schedules and work a different number of days per week. I also have 8 shifts (plus the option to be off), but not all of them need to be covered every day. Each shift needs to be only covered by 1 person. Most of the time, due to shifts not having to be covered, I have enough (or more) employees than needed to cover each shift. However, sometimes I have 1 fewer employee than shifts to be covered. Specifically, I want to have the flexibility to assign shift 1 and shift 2 (they both occur everyday) to the same person if needed.

I have tried modifying the lines of code constraining number of shifts per day.

Original:

```py
for e in range(num_employees):
        for d in range(num_days):
            model.Add(sum(work[e, s, d] for s in range(num_shifts)) == 1)
```

I have tried adding the following code snippet to allow shifts 1 and 2 to be scheduled together (and thus sum up to 2).

```py
for e in range(num_employees):
        for d in range(num_days):
            model.Add((work[e, 1, d] + work[e, 2, d]) <= 2)
```

However, this seems to schedule worker 0 as having both shifts 1 and 2 extremely frequently.

Comment: The issue is unclear. Is it that you expect the distribution of the the double assignment shift to be uniform across all workers, but worker 0 is taking it noticeably more frequently than the other workers?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. Yes, that is the case. Also, when worker 1 is supposed to be off, they are assigned to being off ('O') as well as taking shifts 1 and 2.

Comment: If you allow 2 shifts at the same time, you cannot expect the solver not to use it. If you want to discourage it, you need to add a penalty to the objective when this happens.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. It looks to me that a penalty when both shifts 1 and 2 are scheduled doesn't fit neatly into any of the existing penalties or constraints. Instead, it seems best to just write a new penalty specifically for this case much like the excess cover penalty, if I'm thinking about this correctly.